# JsonNullable object is always has isPresent value = true

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a file with a json format. It stores the json object that I use in my tests. I convert this file to an object using objectmapper and it converts fine, but there is one problem. All fields in the object have a wrapper type of JsonNullabel. The problem is the following - all JsonNullabel objects even if they contain the null property value IsPresent = true. Because of this, the "orElse" and "isPresent" methods do not work correctly. And I get NPE. How can I make sure that when converting from a string or a file with json, these fields are equal to "false" if there is a null value inside?

Json example:

```
{
  "id": 12345,
  "mdmCode": 12345,
  "mdmLegalStatusCode": "Enterprise",
  .......................
}
```

I've tried this config for objectMapper:
ObjectMapper config:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JsonNullableModule());
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using @JsonDeserialize [Jackson annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) on your class members that can be null in json and you want to have value "false" instead of null, like this:

```
public class MyJsonClass {
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    public String nullableMember;
}

public class CustomDeserializer
  extends StdDeserializer<String> {

    public CustomDeserializer() { 
        this(null); 
    } 

    public CustomDeserializer(Class<?> vc) { 
        super(vc); 
    }

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext context) {
        String text = jsonparser.getText();
        if (null == text) {
          text = "false";
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, I cannot influence this in any way. This dto object imports from spring starter